# Return false on addEventListener submit still submits the form?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
var form = document.forms[0]; 
form.addEventListener("submit", function(){
  var email = form.elements['answer_13829'].value;
  if( email == 'geobraks@yahoo.ca') {
     alert('redirecting the user...');
     window.location = 'xxxx';
     return false;
  }
});
```

I don't understand - it still submits the form. Can someone patch my code and make it work?

Comment: Another oddity: I can add onsubmit attribute to form, and do form.addEventListener, and they both seem to run. Is that a browser bug?

Comment: Another oddity: onsubmit="return false;" does stop the form from submitting.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You need to use the [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault) method of the event object.

Note that neither `addEventListener()` nor `preventDefault()` are supported in IE <= 8.

```
var form = document.forms[0]; 
form.addEventListener("submit", function(evt){
  var email = form.elements['answer_13829'].value;
  if( email == 'geobraks@yahoo.ca') {
     evt.preventDefault();
     alert('redirecting the user...');
     window.location = 'xxxx';
  }
});
```

Comment: @yossi: IE does have its own equivalent API.

Comment: @TimDown What is that API?

Comment: @allyourcode: `document.selection` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535869(v=vs.85).aspx) and `TextRange` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535872(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score -4):

the `return false;`
it's work on jQuery bind function only