# Stop form submission with submit eventlistener

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I'm trying to stop a form from submitting using the submit `eventlistener`. My anonymous function runs but the form still submits, even with return false at the end of the function. There are no JS errors being thrown.

Am I making some stupid mistake?

```
<form id="highlight">
    Row: <input type="text" name="rows" value="1" id="rows">
    Column: <input type="text" name="cells" value="1" id="cells">
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Highlight" id="Submit">
</form>

<script>
var highlight_form = document.getElementById('highlight');
highlight_form.addEventListener('submit', function() {
        alert('hi');
    return false;
}, false);
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [return false on addEventListener submit still submits the form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924036/return-false-on-addeventlistener-submit-still-submits-the-form)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I always call `event.preventDefault()` on event listeners that I want to cancel the event for, as well as return `false`.  This always works for me.

```
<script>
var highlight_form = document.getElementById('highlight');

highlight_form.addEventListener('submit', function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('hi');
    return false;

}, false);
</script>
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me when I change return false to return true (or return).

Comment: @zeuf and still using `event.preventDefault()` or no?

Answer (score 1):

To prevent form submission, I've always used the "onclick" event to call a javascript method which will do something and then submit from there.  You can also setup the form as follows:

```
<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
First name: <input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Once submitted, the validateForm() method can prevent submission if necessary:

```
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("First name must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this is the way I would do it :

```
function validate (form)
{
    // return false if some fields are not right
}

function setup_form_validation (form)
{
    form.addEventListener (
        'submit',
        function (f) { // closure to pass the form to event handler
            return function (evt) {
                if (!validate (f)) evt.preventDefault();
                // Return status doesn't work consistently across browsers,
                // and since the default submit event will not be called in case
                // of validation failure, what we return does not matter anyway.
                // Better return true or nothing in case you want to chain other
                // handlers to the submit event (why you would want do that is
                // another question)
            };
        } (form),
    false);
}
```

I would rather have a boolean holding the form validation status, though. Better update the status each time a field changes than do the check only when the user tries to submit the whole form.

And of course this will fail in IE8- and other older browsers. You would need yet another bloody event abstraction layer to make it work everywhere.