# Stopping form submission with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I want to interrupt and prevent a form from submitting using jQuery. Here's my form markup:

```
<div id="register-box">
        <div id="register-box-inner">
            <h2>Register</h2>
            <form action="/register" method="post" id="register-form">
                <p><label for="username">Username:</label><input type="text" name="username"></p>
                <p><label for="password">Password:</label><input type="password" name="password"></p>
                <p><label for="email">E-mail:</label><input type="text" name="email"></p>
                <p><input type="submit" value="Register" class="register"></p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and my Javascript code thus far:

```
$('#register-form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("hi");
});
```

Problem is, the form still goes through. I wanted to submit the form using AJAX but with a fallback for users who don't have Javascript enabled. No errors pop up in the Javascript console, either.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop form submission with submit eventlistener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915893/stop-form-submission-with-submit-eventlistener)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$("form").live("submit", function() {
        alert("hi");
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. I think the problem is the fact that I have this form markup on the page with `display: none`, and then I'm using a jQuery lightbox plugin to show the form, and it's essentially copying the markup. So I end up having two `register-form` IDs on my page. Any way around that?

Comment: are you getting the alert comming up and if so how many times

Comment: ok your question is wrong then as you are never firing the onlick you may need to use live as you are appending to the dom, I have changed my answer slightly

Answer (score 1):

Try returning `false` from the handler.

```
$('#register-form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("hi"); 
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<p><input type="submit" value="Register" class="register" onclick="submit(); return false;"></p>
```