# Submit form via JavaScript to the correct Post action URL in the background

Tags: javascript, html, forms, form-submit, onsubmit

I have the following form:

```
<div id="another"><form action='/post' name='submitform' id="submitform" method='post' class='pure-form'>

  [...]

  <textarea columns="40" rows="4" name='entry[body]' id="statement">
  </textarea>

  <input type='submit' id="submitbutton" name="btnSubmit" value="save" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">

</form></div>
```

When the user clicks on the `submit` button I want the form to be processed first by a script that will check the contents of `#statement` and then do a Post request for the form in the **background**. I prefer to do it in JavaScript (not jQuery).

I tried using

```
 document.querySelector('#submitform').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log('attempt');
   // so smth to submit the form in background - what?
 });
```

but it doesn't seem to "catch" the form and it still submits...

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE - had a typo in html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915893/stop-form-submission-with-submit-eventlistener

Comment: Don't you what to change action attr with JavaScript?

Comment: @Yevgen yes but how?

Comment: I suppose this.form.action =

Comment: @Yevgen it still submits for some reason. Maybe it's because of the name of my submit button?

Comment: Your code works on my end. https://jsfiddle.net/vux3o7jL/ Logs `'attempt'` and doesn't submit.

Comment: Maybe it's because I have this form inside of a DIV? Because when I move it out of that DIV it works, but when it's inside it doesn't - see code update

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vux3o7jL/1/ Doesn't seem to make a difference here

Comment: Probably has to do something with styles - probably this div is loading after i attach the event to the click... so how to deal with that?

Comment: Is the `div` dynamically generated with JavaScript? If not, putting the `script` after the `div` should work. You can also use the [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event.

Comment: @TiiJ7 Yes, thank you! `DOMContentLoaded` was exactly what I needed. Could you please add the answer so I can accept it and also – is this DOMContentLoaded compatible or is it maybe just better to use `onSubmit` attribute in the form and get a function handling that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we deduced in the comments, the code works, but the submit handler was bound before the `<form>` was fully loaded.

One way to solve this is to put the code inside a listener for the [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event. [Support for `DOMContentLoaded`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=domcontentloaded) is rather good, with only IE8 having problems with it (although it doesn't support `addEventListener` either anyway).

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    // ...
});
```

Another way is to put the `<script>` below the `<form></form>` tag.

There is also the inline `onsubmit=...`, but inline JavaScript is considered bad practice nowadays for various reasons (mostly maintainability). You should only really use this if you need to support very old browsers that can't bind events otherwise.

As for submitting the form in the "background" you can [use AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery). There are a lot of great resources/tutorials for this.

Answer (score 1):

Your html is invalid remove the first `</form>` tag. 
This way all elements will be associated with the same form.

```
<form action='/post' name='submitform' id="submitform" method='post' class='pure-form'>
   [...] 
   <textarea columns="40" rows="4" name='entry[body]' id="statement"></textarea>
   <input type='submit' id="submitbutton" name="btnSubmit" value="save" class="pure-button pure-button-primary"> 
</form>
```

see it working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qxay2seb/)

Comment: sorry i had a typo in html