# How to associate condition-reaction with document.querySelector?

Tags: javascript, html, methods, conditional-statements

I don't know how to link the following condition-reactions to *passid* form input id:
I don't know where to put the `document.querySelector()` method so that indexed contion-reactions will be associated with it.

Here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Password - form</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <form>
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="passid" />
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Sign In" />
        </form>

        <script>

            function passType() {
                var password = ["p1", "p2", "p3", "p4", "p5"];

                if (password.indexOf > -1) {
                    alert("That's great! Thank you!");
                } else {
                    alert("Wrong, try again");
                }

                if (password.indexOf > -1) {
                    alert("It's wrong, you have one more try...");
                } else {
                    alert("Get out now!");
                    window.close();
                }
            }
        passType();

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

How should this be done?

Comment: What is `password.indexOf` trying to do? (It won't work the way you have it.)

Comment: There was a "Prompt" before but I've now added a form and tries to associate the script to the form via querySelector. I'm new to JS --- I think the password(var).indexOf just refers to the variable.

Comment: Have you checked Barmar's answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you're asking how to get the value the user typed into the password field. That's `document.getElementById("passid").value`. So you would write:

```
if (password.indexOf(document.getElementById("passid").value) > -1) {
    alert("That's great! Thank you!");
}
```

Note that calling `passType()` in the top-level of the script won't work. That will run when the page is first loaded, not wait for the user to fill in the password. You should call it when the user submits the form. You should do:

```
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", passAll);
```

You should also change the `passAll()` function so it calls `Event.preventDefault()` if the user enters an incorrect password, to prevent submitting the form. See

[return false on addEventListener submit still submits the form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924036/return-false-on-addeventlistener-submit-still-submits-the-form)

Also, checking a password in client-side Javascript is not very secure. There's nothing stopping the user from modifying the script or bypassing it. Passwords should be checked on the server, so that the user cannot override it.

Answer (score 5):

These are *some points* that I would want to focus on :

1. To select a particular element using the query selector, remember these :

   > - If you happen to know the **id** of the element, use `document.getElementById(id)`. This is the most prominent way of selection, as usually **id** is unique for all elements.
   > - If you happen to know the **class** of the element, use `document.getElementsByClassName(class)`. This method has certain amount of risk, as there could be more than one element with the same **class**.
   > - If you happen to know the **tagName** of the element, use `document.getElementsByTagName(tag)`.
   > - The easiest way to achieve element selection is by using `document.querySelector('tag'/ '.class'/ '#id')`. You can [refer here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp) for more about the same.
2. Now, you need to understand that your function `passType()`, which here *validates* the entered password based in the array of passwords you have defined, needs to be called **only after the user has input the password and click the *Sign In* button**.

   > In order to achieve this, you will have to **bind** the *submit* event to an `EventListener`. This can be achieved by using `document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', passType);`
3. Now finally, as per the code snippet you provided, you want to give the user a **second chance** in case the user enters a wrong password at first attempt. For this, you will have to **store** the *attempt counts* in a variable. Also, the `EventListener` of the **submit** action button keeps bubbling, and in order to prevent it, you need to use `event.preventDefault()`

Keeping all this in mind, I believe this will solve your problem. Here is the **rectified code snippet :**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Password - form</title>
</head>

<body>

<form>
<label>Password</label>
<input type="password" id="passid"/>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Sign In"/>
</form>

<script>

var attemptCount = 0;

function passType(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var enteredValue = document.querySelector('form').querySelector('#passid').value;
    var password = ['p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4', 'p5'];

    if (password.indexOf(enteredValue) > -1) {
        alert("That's great! Thank you!");
    }
    else {
        attemptCount++;
        alert('Wrong, try again');
        if (attemptCount <= 1) {
            alert("It's wrong, you have one more try...");
            document.querySelector('form').querySelector('#passid').value = '';
        } else {
            alert('Get out now!');
            window.close();
        }
    }
}

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', passType);

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Feel free to ask any queries you have on the same.

Answer (score 4):

**How to access form using query selector?**

```
let frm = document.querySelector('form');
```

**Then Listen for its `submit` event.**

```
frm.addEventListener('submit', passType);
```

**How can you access the input password?**

You need to make changes to your function. First add the following to the top of your "passType" function. The following snippet saves the user input into the variable `pass`.

```
let p = frm.querySelector('#passid');//Get the DOM node
let pass = p.value;//Get the input value
```

Now Modify `if (password.indexOf > -1)` to `if (password.indexOf(pass) > -1)` to check for actual input.

**DEMO**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Password - form</title>
</head>

<body>

  <form>
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="passid" />
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Sign In" />
    <!-- We also have input type = "button" and events for both >>> onsubmit & onclick. -->
  </form>

  <script>
    function passType() {
      let p = frm.querySelector('#passid');
      let pass = p.value;
      var password = ["p1", "p2", "p3", "p4", "p5"];

      if (password.indexOf(pass) > -1) {
        alert("That's great! Thank you!");
      } else {
        alert("Wrong, try again");
        if (password.indexOf(pass) > -1) {
          alert("It's wrong, you have one more try...");
        } else {
          alert("Get out now!");
          window.close();
        }
      }

    }

    let frm = document.querySelector('form');
    frm.addEventListener('submit', passType);
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This answer gives the user only one chance to enter a password. I believe @JohnDoea wants to give the user one more attempt before throwing an alert of "Get out now". Please try updating this answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a way to do something with the password field upon form submission you might want something along these lines:

```js
// listen for submit events on the form
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', doSubmit);

// our form submit handler
function doSubmit(event) {
  
  // prevent submission
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  
  // get the password field
  // event.target is the form
  // could alternatively query by id using document.getElementById('passid')
  var passwordField = event.target.querySelector('#passid');
  
  // do something with the field or its value
  console.log(passwordField.value);
  
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Password</label>
  <input type="password" id="passid" />
  <input type="submit" value="Sign In" />
</form>
```