# JS Client Form Validation - Form still submits when formValidation function via eventListener for "submit" event returns false

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm still relatively a beginner in JS, so this likely is just me not having that great fundamentals in the language.

I'm trying to create timestamp objects (think youtube timestamps, but with a title instead of just the time) using a very simple HTML form, validated before sending the post request.

To submit the form I intentionally do not use JQuery or an inline event handler, as I would like to use an eventListener. However with an eventListener, even when the form is invalid, the form is still submitted.

HTML and javascript excerpts with some variables replaced with placeholders below:

```
# piece of timestamp_create_form.html
        <h3> New Timestamp </h3>
        <form class="timestamp-form" name="timestamp-form" action="URL_PLACEHOLDER" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="TOKEN_PLACEHOLDER">

            <div class="input-row">
                <div>
                    <input type="text" maxlength="100" id="id_name" placeholder="Timestamp-Title" class="input-title" name="name">
                    <label for="name"> Timestamp-Title </label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" id="id_time" maxlength="8" value="00:00:00" name="time" class="input-time">
                    <label for="time"> Time </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-buttons">
                <div><input type="submit" class="btn" value="Create Timestamp"></div>
                <div><a class="button" id="cancel-timestamp-creation" href="#"> Cancel </a></div>
            </div>
        </form>


# timestamp.js
// Add Event Listener to the form for the "onsubmit" event
document.forms['timestamp-form'].addEventListener('submit', function(){ return validateTimestampForm();} );
// I also tried this second variant, it did not work either
// document.forms['timestamp-form'].addEventListener('submit', validateTimestampForm);


function validateTimestampForm(){
    const timestampForm = document.forms['timestamp-form'];
    
    const timestamp_time_string = timestampForm['time'].value;
    const hours = parseInt(timestamp_time_string.substring(0,2));
    const minutes = parseInt(timestamp_time_string.substring(3,5));
    const seconds = parseInt(timestamp_time_string.substring(6,8));
    let timestamp_seconds = 3600*hours + 60*minutes + seconds;
    if (timestamp_seconds > 7200){
        alert("The time you entered is past the duration of the audio file!");
        return false;
    }
    
    const timestamp_name = timestampForm['name'].value;
    if (timestamp_name === ""){
        alert("Timestamp title must be filled out!");
        return false; 
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

Where is my mistake?

I was originally using an inline event handler there `onsubmit="return validateForm()"`, but for best practice reasons and to be able to disallow inline javascript via CSP I would like to move away from that.

Answers to other questions to this that I found either refer to JQuery or use inline event handlers, both of which I would like to avoid. Lastly one recommended passing the validation-function directly to the eventListener instead of creating an anonymous function, which I tried (see comments above) and it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are like doing this inline for rejections:

```
onsubmit="false"
```

which is different from:

```
onsubmit="return false"
```

I would just do it inline:

```
 <form onsubmit="return validateTimestampForm()"...
```

Perhaps you can define an onclick() event on the button and submit the form manually:

```
<div><input id="sb" type="button" class="btn" value="Create Timestamp" ></div>
<script>
    document.getElementById("sb").onclick = event=>{
        if (validateTimestampForm()) document.forms['timestamp-form'].submit();
    }
</script>
```

*** EDIT ***

So this is the final solution we have come up with:

```
document.forms['timestamp-form'].addEventListener('submit', function(event){ 
    if (!validateTimestampForm()) event.preventDefault(); 
} );
```

Comment: The issue with inline event handlers is that they do not play nice with Content Security Policy (CSP) measures, which prevent all inline javascript. And given that it's anyway best practice to not use inline javascript, it seems more sensible to me to use an EventListener.

I'm not entirely sure how to properly express "return false" with an eventListener. `addEventListener('submit', return function(){ return validateForm()});` is syntactically incorrect, so if I have to put a return statement in there somewhere, I'm not entirely sure how.

Comment: What do you mean by CSP preventing all inline javascript? There should be a way in declaring the CSP such that it allows inline javascript.

Comment: I agree that you can use nonce/hashes to allow you to run a particular case of inline javascript, but given that this event in particular should not be that difficult and avoidable it seems not quite as elegant to go that far.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924036/return-false-on-addeventlistener-submit-still-submits-the-form

Comment: That fixed it!
Yep, that was the problem. For future readers: It was all about preventing Default behaviour of the submit action of the validation was false, that needed to be suppressed manually. 
I'll mark this question as a duplicate of the other one, thank you for your help! I must've missed that one.

Comment: I think you will still need to submit the form with a call to .submit().

Comment: That post has been there for almost 10 years. No one has seemed to be able to offer a better solution.

Comment: The submit() call is funnily enough not required. I just live tested this in my dev environment and the following event listener worked (Apologies for atrocious formatting, it's forcibly a oneliner): `document.forms['timestamp-form'].addEventListener('submit', function(e){ 
        const isValid = validateForm();
        if (isValid === false) e.preventDefault();
        return isValid;
    });`

Comment: You nailed it...